# Change background color of selected text

Tags: unity, themes, configuration, gtk

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity and when I select a text (for example to copy something from browser), it has ugly orange background. I want to make it something normal like blue. I tried gnome-color-chooser but it doesn't have that option.

Do you know some way to change it? Maybe there is some gtk conf file where I can just change the color code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

and wherever you see `selected_bg_color` change `#f07746` (orange) to `#0000ff` (bright blue, or whatever color you prefer)

These are system files, so to edit them you'll need to be root like so:

```
 gksudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

Comment: It's great that you included the orange color! I was looking for that color to set it to my windows too (Unfortunately, I am stuck with it sometimes at work)

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep this up-to-date and complete: in 13.10, `gtk.css` imports `gtk-main.css`, so you will actually need to edit:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to install the color-varied versions of Radiance and Ambiance: [Ambiance & Radiance Colors](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/download-ambiance-radiance-colors.html).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambiance-colors radiance-colors
```

And then change the theme with Unity Tweak Tool.

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]