# Text selected is white

Tags: 16.04, themes

Installed theme Paper. But when I select text, the background is white and can not see well what is selected. How can I change?

[image]

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312689/change-background-color-of-selected-text?rq=1

Or you could try a different gtk theme as well.

Comment: The options are different :(