# Invisible Selected Text in Nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, themes

I am using the Paper theme on Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I am renaming a folder/file, I cannot see the selected text, it just appears white. How and from where do I change the settings so that the selected text is visible when renaming? I do not wish to use a different theme. I found one answer to [Change background color of selected text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312689/change-background-color-of-selected-text?rq=1) but the answer is for Ubuntu 12.04, hence asking a new question.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but probably enough if you are willing to poke around a bit. In 16.04 I believe you'll be looking to modify `/usr/share/themes/ThemeName/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css

Comment: Thank you Simplexion and ElderGreek. I will check the answer mentioned and let you know.

Comment: @ElderGeek I have many gtk-* folders in `/usr/share/themes/Paper` - gtk-2.0, gtk-3.0, gtk-3.16, gtk-3.18, gtk-3.20. Will editing just the file you mentioned be sufficient?

Comment: When in doubt backup the file you intend to change and test your results. I provided my best guess in a comment based on what I found under 16.04 in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/
If I were certain I'd write an answer. Best practices indicate you should always backup anything you intend to edit so that you can go back if something goes wrong. Having backed up it never hurts to test in order to prove an approach.